# FactoryGirl issue with Time.zone.today

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm having an issue with FactoryGirl when I try to return the current instances of an object. The object I am dealing with has the following scope:

```
scope :current, -> {activeAtDate}

scope :activeAtDate, lambda{ |date = Time.zone.today| where("? BETWEEN start_date and end_date", date)}
```

At the top of my factories.rb I have:

```
Time.zone = "Melbourne"
```

And the factories in question are:

```
factory :focus do
    title "Test Focus Title"
    store
    pp Time.zone
    start_date Time.zone.today
    end_date Time.zone.today
end

factory :store do
    name "Test store"
    address "This is the address of the test store"
    number "98765432"

    factory :store_with_kpi do

        ignore do
            kpi_count 5
        end

        after(:create) do |store, evaluator|
            create_list(:kpi, evaluator.kpi_count, store: store)
        end

    end

    factory :store_with_focus do

        ignore do
            focus_count 5
        end

        after(:create) do |store, evaluator|
            create_list(:focus, evaluator.focus_count, store: store)
        end
    end
end
```

The 'pp Time.zone' output is:

```
    <ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x007fe7fd1bd630@current_period=
   #<TZInfo::TimezonePeriod: #<TZInfo::TimezoneTransitionDefinition: #<TZInfo::TimeOrDateTime:     1412438400>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneOffset: 36000,3600,AEDT>>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneTransitionDefinition: #    <TZInfo::TimeOrDateTime: 1428163200>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneOffset: 36000,0,AEST>>>,
     @name="Melbourne",
     @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Australia/Melbourne>,
     @utc_offset=nil>
```

And finally the relevant test:

```
it "We can get all current focuses as JSON" do
    @store = FactoryGirl.create(:store_with_focus)
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, store: @store)
    sign_in @user

    get :get_focus, {}

    #Of course we want to have a successful response
    expect(response).to be_success


    #But maybe, we also want the number of objects returned to be correct as well
    expect(json.count).to eq(5)
end
```

Yet if I output the created focuses in the controller spec, they are created with start_date and end_date being in UTC and thus my spec fails. Let me know if there is any information I can provide, and I have already tried:

- Adding a Timezone to the store_with_focus factories and then passing that in from the controller spec
- start_date {Time.zone.today}

Thanks in advance for the help.